# Response body to List or Map in Spring

Tags: java, spring, okhttp

I am developing a web-app that consumes API REST from a server and shows data to front.
I am not sure how to do the call, and how to manage the response, in Spring.

I have a class Controller which is mapped to the POST request that is the action of a button for showing the info that is on the server, the one that gives me back one REST API call.
Here is the method that I am talking about. What I want is as simple as to show the data, in these case categories, in a table which I will pass to the view. But I cannot (don't know) how to convert what I get to something like List or Map...

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/showAreas")
public String getAllAreas(Model model) throws IOException {

    TokenRepositoryImpl token = new TokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenId = token.getToken();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8888/api/1.0/test/project/categories").get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenId.getAccess_token()).build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    System.out.println(response.body().string());

    //This is what I need: List<JSONObject> areas = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    return "areasView";

}
```

What I get in the sys out is these:
    [{"cat_uid":"8650262225c0e95e609fa16018826000","cat_name":"X XXX","cat_total_processes":X},{"cat_uid":"2...]

Answer (score 1):

Add the `List or Map` to your `Model` object which is passed in parameters, and then you can access it on front end using Model object again. e.g:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8888/api/1.0/test/project/categories").get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenId.getAccess_token()).build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
model.setAttribute("response",response.body());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ResponseEntity` in spring

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/showAreas")
public ResponseEntity getAllAreas(Model model) throws IOException {

    TokenRepositoryImpl token = new TokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenId = token.getToken();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8888/api/1.0/test/project/categories").get()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenId.getAccess_token()).build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response.body());

}
```

Comment: That body is the object per se, and it does not contain the body text

Comment: Anyone could help me with that?